# How to write date validation which not allows to over lap dates?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation

So I have `Shift model` with `start_date` and `end_date`

And I would like to write validator which not allow to overlap shifts on each other.

For example:

```
#<Shift id: 88, start_date: "2013-11-11 08:00:00", end_date: "2013-11-12 08:00:00">
```

and I should not be able to create Shift like this:

```
> Shift.create(start_date: "2013-11-12 07:00".to_datetime)
```

How to achieve that?

Comment: You might consider that if one shift always ends when the next one starts then you do not need to store both start and end dates, as one of them is redundant. You can store just the start date, and define the end date by reference to the lowest start date following it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Also u can use this gem: [validates_overlap](https://github.com/robinbortlik/validates_overlap)

Answer (score 0):

You have to add a custom validation here

```
class Shift < ActiveRecord::Base
  validate :does_not_overlap

  def does_not_overlap
    if Shift.exists?("start_date > 2013-11-12 07:00")
      errors.add(:start_date, "cannot overlap")
    end
  end

end
```